# Yew add Javascript onclick function (ssr) (not yet answered)

Tags: javascript, html, rust, yew

I would like to do something like this, where `func` is a Javascript function defined.

```rs
html! {
  <button onclick="func(1, 2, 3)">Click me</button>
}
```

However, the compiler keeps telling me that I'll need to use a rust callback instead. I'm doing ssr, so the way they are trying to make me add rust code to the page just wouldn't work.

Is there a way to just have a javascript function as onclick?

Comment: Why not define a Rust callback that will call JS?

Comment: i was trying to do server side rendering, so the html is all that will be served, no wasm whatsoever

Comment: I have the same situation.  I'm only using yew for SSR with HTMX

Comment: what i did was include an extra script to add a button.onclick function to it programatically, or you can also use the <script> tag, hope that helps